# AngularJs ng-click not working for controller'c local object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to Angular. I went to intro-tutorials on some website.
There I learned that I can access controller functions and controller-local variables using controller-name and without `$scope` service. Like for example:

```
<div ng-controller="someController">
someController.someFunction()
someController.someVariable
</div>
```

I my simple application I have written a controller in `controllers.js` and using it in `home.html`. I have defined the mapping in `app.js`

I provided a `button` tag for it in html but the controller function is just not responding.

Looking at my `js` and `HTML` page you will know what I am trying to accomplish.

Here' **controllers.js**:

```
 app.controller('welcomeStoryPublishCtrl', ['$log','$http',function($log,$http){
    this.wsPublish = {};

    this.publishGroup = function(wsPublish){
        console.log('here');
        $http({
            method:'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:9090/Writer/publishStory',
            header: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
            data: wsPublish
        });
    };
    this.public = function(){
        console.log('from public');
    };
}]);
```

**home.html**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/angular-route.min.js" ></script>
 <script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js"></script>
 <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="welcomeStory">
            
            <span id="wsTitleBub">Title</span>
            <input id="wsTitle" type="text" ng-model="wsPublish.welcomeStoryTitle" />{{wsPublish.welcomeStoryTitle}}
            <h6>Words..</h6>
            <textarea id="wsWords" ng-model="wsPublish.welcomeStoryWords"></textarea>
            <input id="wsPublish" type="button" name="wsPublish" value="Publish" ng-click="pub = !pub" />
            <input id="wsAddShelf" type="button" name="wsAddToShelf" value="Add To Shelf" ng-click="addToShelf()" />
        </div>
        <div id="wsPublishTo" ng-show="pub">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type=submit id="wsgroups" value="Group" ng-click="publishGroup(wsPublish)" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button id="wsPublic" ng-click="public()">Public</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I know that I can do this by injecting `$scope` module dependency and I know controller instantiation always creates a `$scope` object itself.

But what if try doing so like this? What am I doing wrong here?

And here is `app.js`:

```
angular.module('Writer', ['AllControllers','ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider,$Log){
    $routeProvider.when('/Diary',{
        templateUrl:'pages/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginFormController'
    })
    .when('/loginPg',{
        template: 'Hello from app.js'
    })
    .when('/home',{
        templateUrl: './pages/home.html',
        controller: 'welcomeStoryPublishCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo : '/Diary'});
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First off all your input elements are not wrapped in a `<form>` tag and this is why your button should not be working properly. If you insist to use `<button>` it should be in a `<form>` tag so it "submits" the form, if not, go with `<input type="submit"..>`
Lastly, i would suggest you to use services for your http requests as this is a common good practice. :)

Comment: services for http request? like how? can you please tell me more?

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML you have not mentioned the `ng-app` directive neither have you mentioned your controller directive `ng-controller`.

Your HTML

```
<body ng-app="someApp">
    <div>
       <div id="welcomeStory" ng-controller="welcomeStoryPublishCtrl as wsCtrl">
       <!-- Rest of your code -->

       <button ng-click="wsCtrl.public()">Public</button>
```

Your JS

```
var app = angular.module('someApp', []);
app.controller('welcomeStoryPublishCtrl', ['$log','$http',function($log,$http){
this.wsPublish = {};

this.publishGroup = function(wsPublish){
    console.log('here');
    $http({
        method:'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:9090/Writer/publishStory',
        header: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
        data: wsPublish
    }).success(function(data){
        console.log('run success!');
    });
};
this.public = function(){
    console.log('from public');
};
}]);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: For that I am using another js `app.js`. I have updated the question. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing ng-app attribute ?

Comment: no..please see my app.js. I have provided the controller mapping with my home.html page